# Get the opposite of a CIDR Range

Tags: r, ip, cidr

I'd like to make a list of CIDR ranges that represent the addresses outside of the CIDR range I specify.

As a simplified example:

If I have the IP ranges from 8.8.8.8 to 8.8.8.10, I would be able to express this with CIDR ranges 8.8.8.8/31 and 8.8.8.10/32. But how could I express the opposite of these ranges in CIDR notation?

I'm new to CIDR so if this kind of tool exists already in a popular format please excuse my question.

As an additional note, I would like to eventually implement this filtering in R so if you can express your answer using R that would be preferable but I'm really mostly interested in how to build the algorithm to solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, if you have a range (X, Y) of IP addresses and want to represent all IP addresses that are not in (X, Y) then it can be expressed as two ranges: (0.0.0.0, X-1) and (Y+1, 255.255.255.255).

Then you just convert the two ranges into CIDRs. A range may result in multiple CIDRs.

In the specific example you want ranges: (0.0.0.0, 8.8.8.7) and (8.8.8.11, 255.255.255.255). I have no idea of how to do this in R but here is a handy calculator here: http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr

(0.0.0.0, 8.8.8.7):

- 0.0.0.0/5
- 8.0.0.0/13
- 8.8.0.0/21
- 8.8.8.0/29

(8.8.8.11, 255.255.255.255):

- 8.8.8.11/32
- 8.8.8.12/30
- 8.8.8.16/28
- 8.8.8.32/27
- 8.8.8.64/26
- 8.8.8.128/25
- 8.8.9.0/24
- 8.8.10.0/23
- 8.8.12.0/22
- 8.8.16.0/20
- 8.8.32.0/19
- 8.8.64.0/18
- 8.8.128.0/17
- 8.9.0.0/16
- 8.10.0.0/15
- 8.12.0.0/14
- 8.16.0.0/12
- 8.32.0.0/11
- 8.64.0.0/10
- 8.128.0.0/9
- 9.0.0.0/8
- 10.0.0.0/7
- 12.0.0.0/6
- 16.0.0.0/4
- 32.0.0.0/3
- 64.0.0.0/2
- 128.0.0.0/1